# Is a sentence true for two substructures also true for their intersection?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, inner-models

Let $L$ be a first order language and $M$ an interpretation of $L$.
If $A$ and $B$ are two substructures of $M$ and their intersection $C=A\cap B\ne \emptyset$, then is it the case that every sentence (in language $L$) true for both $A$ and $B$ is also true for $C$?

By "intersection" of $A$ and $B$, I mean the smaller substructure whose domain is the intersection of the domain of $A$ and $B$.

I came to this conjecture when I learned that there was a **smallest standard submodel** in a universe of some set theories (such as $ZF$) if there was a standard submodel in it. The **smallest standard submodel** is the intersection of all the standard submodels. But is the intersection of any two standard submodels still a standard submodel? If so, considered every standard submodel is nothing more than a substructure of the universe for which a group of sentences, i.e. the axioms of some set theory, are true, can we further generalize it into the conjecture I mentioned above?

I haven't found a proof or disproof for this so far (actually I am not very good at it). Can anyone prove it or give a counterexample?

-----update----

The question in the title is trivial. Thanks for answers from Andrej Bauer and 喻良. But whether the intersection of two standard submodels of $ZF$ is still a stanadard submodel? (which is my earliest concern and let's only focus on $ZF$ or $ZFC$ here)

Comment: My answer to this question gives an example of two transitive models of ZFC whose intersection does not satisfy ZF: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297756/intersection-of-two-generic-extensions/297769#297769

Comment: This link is very helpful. I’ll reed it again after I learn more about forcing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\mathcal C$ is any substructure of a structure $\mathcal A$, then $\mathcal C$ is the intersection of $\mathcal A$ and an isomorphic copy of it, $\mathcal A'$, inside a larger structure $\mathcal M$. (Take an isomorphic copy of $\mathcal A$ and combine it with $\mathcal A$, identifying corresponding elements of $\mathcal C$.) So a sentence is preserved by intersections if and only if it's preserved by substructures. And that's well-known to be the case only for sentences equivalent to universal sentences.

Comment: The way you demonstrate that a sentence is preserved by intersections implies it's preserved by substructures is impressive! And thank you for this informative answer!

Answer (score 6):

Of course not. For example, consider the empty language. A model is just a set. Take $M = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $A = \{1, 3\}$ and $B = \{2, 3\}$. Both $A$ and $B$ satisfy $\exists x y . x \neq y$, but $A \cap B$ does not.

**Supplemental:** The OP comments that the simple answer makes the original question look stupid. I disagree, no question is stupid. In fact, very often a seemingly stupid question can lead to interesting things.

So we have discovered that the answer to the question is negative. But now, rather than hiding in shame, we should drill some more, by asking trickier questions. For instance, can we put some further restrictions, either on the language, the statements, or the substructures, so that the answer becomes positive?

For example, suppose our language only has function symbols (on relation symbols, the only primitive relation is $=$). If the statement $\phi$ under consideration contains no $\exists$ and $\lor$, is its validity preserved by substructures? What if we have a statement with only $\forall$, $\land$ and $=$ (so we drop implications as well)?

Comment: The question does specify that the intersection is nonempty. But of course you could just add $0$ to all the sets and have the sentence say “there are two distinct elements”.

Comment: @GabeConant: ah, I miseed that point. I fixed the answer to fit the question as stated.

Comment: Yes! It's quite simple! This answer just makes my question look stupid.

Comment: As I tell my students, there are no stupid questions. Actually, let me make a comment about that in my answer.

Comment: *The OP comments that the simple answer makes the original question look stupid.* The "Of course not" is also  condescending and could very well contribute to OP's impression.

Comment: I copied "Of course not" from 喻 良's answer to indicate that my answer was a simpler version of his answer. But by now the answers have diverged so it's kind of pointless. However, I am not going to delete it, because objectively speaking, on a research-level site like this one, the answer is rightfully considered easy and rather trivial. I do not see you complaining about the same thing in 喻 良's answer, so what's your point, other than an attempt at political correctness? If you're complaining that I made the OP feel stupid, then I recommend that you read the entire answer and the comments.

Comment: My point is that you pretend to care about whether you make the OP feel "stupid" or not, and at the same time you use condescending language. 喻 良 showed no such hypocrisy, only condescension. There are intermediate between "political correctness" and "being hurtful".

Comment: @Zhiwei, am I condescending, hypocritical, or both?

Comment: Hi Andrej Bauer, I was ok with your answer and didn’t feel uncomfortable. Maybe I shouldn’t have appended that sentence in my comment by which I was only making fun of myself for being stuck on such a simple question. Your supplemental in the answer also leaded me into a deeper thinking. However, I believe there must be some authors who are a little sensitive, so avoiding words that might incur misunderstanding will be better.

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ be the language of multiplication, let $M=\mathbf{R},\ A=[0,1), B=(0,1]$. Then $\exists x(xx=x)$ is true in $A$ and in $B$ but not in $A \cap B$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. For example, if $g$ and $h$ are mutually Cohen reals, then $L[g]\cap L[h]=L$. But both $L[g]$ and $L[h]$ satisfy $V\neq L$.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample! I can stop my useless struggling on that problem now. But I need more time to digest Cohen reals.

Comment: Cohen forcing does not really matter here. The point is that $g$ and $h$ form a ``minimal pair". Most mutually reals have such property.

Comment: Hi, I'm still wondering whether the intersection of any two standard submodels is still a standard submodel. Could you please explain this for me?

Comment: Of course $L$ is the least proper class model of $ZF$. If you want a standard set model, you need an inaccessible cardinal.